# How to put the marquee label upright?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<view style="background-color: #39B54A;height: 100vh;">
    <marquee style="transform:rotate(0deg,0deg,0deg,0deg);background-           color: #0081FF;" behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello</marquee>
</view>

</body>
</html>
```

The effect I want is like this,Is there any good way?

[image: CSS rotated marquee]

Comment: Just FYI, the marquee element is [considered obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee). Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below:

```css
marquee {
  background-color: #39B54A;
  width: 100vh; /* width based on screen height */
  transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(calc(-50% - 50vw)); /* rotate and center */
  transform-origin:top left;
}


body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello</marquee>
```

And since `marquee` is obsolete, You can do it like below:

```css
.marquee {
  background-color: #39B54A;
  width: 100vh; /* width based on screen height */
  transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(calc(-50% - 50vw)); /* rotate and center */
  transform-origin:top left;
}

.marquee > span {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  animation:move 4s alternate infinite linear;
}
@keyframes move {
  to {
     transform:translateX(-100%);
     left:100%;
  }
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee"><span>Hello</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform:rotate(90deg)

```html
<view style="background-color: #39B54A;height: 100vh;">
    <marquee style="transform:rotate(90deg);background-           color: #0081FF;" behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello</marquee>
</view>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it, but the subtitles did not reach the bottom completely and went back